# C++ template argument deduction/substition failed

Tags: c++, templates

I'm using a template library in which class B is a templated class parametrized by class A.  I have a declaration

```
template <class A, template <class A> class B>
void foo(){
   B<A> x;
}
```

later on I want to invoke this as

```
foo<A, B>();
```

where X is a concrete class in the library and Y is a particular templated concrete class in the library.  However, I get the titled error abour template argument deduction/substitution failed.  If I change the declaration of foo to remove the templates and subsitute in X and Y, then it all works ok.  I also tried

```
foo<X, Y<X> >();
```

which failed with the same message.  Can someone explain why this is happening?

I'm using gcc 5.3.0

Here's a complete example which gives the indicated behavior

```
#include <vector>
template <class A, template <class A> class B>
void foo() {
   B<A> x;
}
void bar() {
   foo<int, std::vector>();
}
```

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] as required please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues that I can see.

First is that `std::vector` takes more than one template argument so the template template parameter `template<class A> class B` will never match `std::vector`.

Second and slightly less of an issue is that the `class A` here `template<class A> class B` shadows the previous `class A` here `template <class A/*here*/, template <class A> class B>`

To fix both of these issues you can declare the second template argument as an nameless variadic template like so: `template <class...> class B`.

Combining everything you get:

```
#include <vector>
template <class A, template <class...> class B>
void foo() {
    B<A> x;
}
void bar() {
    foo<int, std::vector>();
}
```

Edit:

If you would like to only use B in the form of `B<A>` you could do one of a few things:

```
template <class A, template <class...> class B>
void foo() {
    using C = B<A>;
    C x;
}
```

OR:

```
template <class A, template <class...> class B, class C = B<A>>
void foo() {
    C x;
}
```

OR (depending on the larger point of your code) you could just accept the whole thing as one template parameter:

```
template <class A>
void foo() {
    A x;
}
void bar() {
    foo<std::vector<int>>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This does work, but I'd like to indicate that class B is always used as B<A>.  Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Thanks.  Your second solution looks best for me, since, in the real code, there are variables just declared as instances of A, in addition to those declared as B<A>.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` is not templated on one class, so it does not match your type. You can coerce it to match by

```
template <class X> using MyVector = std::vector<X>;
```

and that will work. C++17 will just plain fix this to work as you expected it to.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm glad to see that it's planned to be fixed in c++17.